# ElasticSearch plugin for New Relic not showing metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, newrelic, agent

I'm trying to make the new relic elastic search plugin work, the following is the website of the author:

[New Relic Plug in Github](https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/elasticsearch-newrelic)

I've followed all the instructions and even see that the plugin has been installed succesfuly when I run in my server the command

```
'curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_newrelic?pretty'
```

, I even get the response that should confirm everything has installed just fine:

```
' {
  "configuration" : {
    "agents" : {
      "http" : true,
      "pool" : true,
      "transport" : true,
      "fs" : true,
      "indices" : true,
      "network" : true
    },
    "refreshInterval" : 10
   }
  }'
```

However, when I log to my newrelic account not a single statistic is shown, either for JVM or whatsoever, nor I see the indices being monitored.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? PS: ElasticSearch is not running as a service and I DO have the new relic java agent properly installed. Also I have configured **bin/elasticsearch.in.sh** as it should be.

Thanks in advance!

JM.